# Using setlayout for a listview on a tabhost

Tags: basic4android

I am trying to adjust a ListView's appearance within a Tabhost with the following code - but keep getting a null error. When I remove the setlayout line - all is fine, but my ListView is off by just a hair from what I'd like.

```
TabHost1.AddTabWithIcon2("",tab1bmp1,tab1bmp2,ListView1)
ListView1.SetLayout(0,0,100%x,75%y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a Panel in the TabHost, and then add the ListView in the Panel.